# How to get IP Address of Server (Socket) in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm creating a simple chat program that connects two android devices and they can send simple message
I run the server with Socket on a port (1234 for example)

The problem is from the client i do not know the server IP Address. (and i dont want to enter it manually)
is there a way to find a server that is running on a specific port?or can i run the server on some specific static IP that i can give it to clients?

if not is there another way to communicate with android devices that works on Android 2.2+(don't want to use wifi direct) ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast a udp message from the server specifying your ip in the message. Let the client receive the broadcast and use that msg as the ip address to connect to the socket. (PS : The broadcast receiver must b allowed to receive broadcasts). And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Assign one SERVER predominantly for getting details such as IP ADDRESS, PORT number,etc.. from all the clients.
Each client when activated will contact the SERVER to register itself first and will get the details(IP ADDRESS,etc) of other device to communicate.
Now they can start waiting for specific device.

Comment: Still , the clients do not know the IP of server to communicate with , That's my problem

Answer (score 0):

On 4.1 you can use Mutlicast DNS for service discovery via the `NsdManager` (if you are on the same network). If you need this to work over the Internet/3G there is really no good way to do it. You could use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to notify clients about the server address, but in any case you will need one 'real' server on a stable address that all participants can reach.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html

Answer (score 0):

InetAddress.getLocalHost(); doesnot work for me but ya below code work for me

```
DhcpInfo dhcp = mWifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
int dhc = dhcp.serverAddress;

String dhcS = ( dhc & 0xFF)+ "."+((dhc >> 8 ) & 0xFF)+"."+((dhc >> 16 ) & 0xFF)+"."+((dhc >> 24 ) & 0xFF);
```

dhcS contains IP address of server,I used for Wireless connection between multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
 connectionSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```

Answer (score -1):

No the port can never be fixed with a IP. It is always provided by the user. To know the IP address of the server automatically, you can run this program associated with the chat program.

```
public class Net {
  public Net() throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println(ia);
    ia = InetAddress.getByName("local host");
    System.out.println(ia);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
    Net a = new Net();
  }
}
```

You run can this program by the help of a button which is associated with your chat program.

Comment: thanks for answer but both lines output this: localhost/127.0.0.1 which is a local IP and not correct

Comment: yeah it will show unless you don't connect to a network. both client and server if they work on different machines need a network to connect. or if both client and server work on a same machine 127.0.0.1 will work.like connect server and client to a same wifi network and then run this program. remember the network should be same in server and client.

Comment: they are not on the same machine , if they were i wouldn't need IP Address since they both have same IP

Comment: okay if they are not then connect them with a network. for example you can connect both to the wifi hotspot of your mobile. and then you run this program.

Comment: is there a way to determine it's IP if they are both connected to the same router?

Comment: yah then also you run this program. and you will know the ip